# How to check if a object is a type of enum in arraylist in java?

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist, enums

I have a simple question. Say I have an arrayList that will hold three different types from my enum below. How do I check to see if one of my items in my arraylist is a specific enum in java? For instance, how do I check to see is a object is a small through a if statement? I'm pretty new to using arraylists so I am not to sure what I can and can't do with them.

```
// My ArrayList...

ArrayList<sizes> myItems = new ArrayList<sizes>; 

// My enum...

     enum itemType { 

          SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE }
}
```

Comment: what's `sizes`? is it `itemType`?

Comment: Yes it would be the itemType.

Comment: "how do I check to see is a object is a small through a if statement" `if (yourObject == itemType.SMALL)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example if you want to check if first item is large:

```
if(myItems.get(0)==itemType.LARGE)
    System.out.println("true");
```

A more general solution:

```
for (int i=0;i<myItems.size();i++) 
    if(myItems.get(i)==itemType.SMALL)
        System.out.println("item at index: "+i+" is small");
```